# Poner variable php a ajax dependiendo del nombre de la clase y el contenido

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

El titulo no explica mucho, pero yo tengo un codigo que va dando un numero a la clase, porque está en un `foreach`, sería

```
<button class='accept ".$accept++."'>Accept</button>
```

el **$accept++** va sumandose uno por cada vez que se pasa por el foreach, y quiero que si das click al botón se mande una peticion *ajax* con el contenido del row:

Se explica así:
Si tengo nombre Juan y accept 1, quiero que mande petición con esos datos, luego sería Luis y accept 2, etc...

AJAX:

```
$( ".accept" ).click(function() { // aqui quiero el accept 1, accept 2...
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "url.php",
         data: {'nombre':'<?php echo $nombre; ?>'}, //el nombre del row sacado con foreach
         success: function(){
             console.log("Yes");
         },
         error: function(){
             console.log("error");
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tú puedes perfectamente **asignar la misma clase a los botones, no una clase incremental**, crear un *listener*  para los botones de esa clase y luego a través de `this` puedes obtener cualquier dato del botón que fue presionado.

Por ejemplo:

```js
$('button.my-buttons').click(function() {
  var $btnId = $(this).prop('id');
  var $btnName = $(this).prop('name');
  var $btnValue = $(this).prop('value');
  var $btnClass = $(this).prop('class');
  var $btnText = $(this).text();

console.log(`ID: ${$btnId} | name: ${$btnName} | value: ${$btnValue} | clase: ${$btnClass} | texto: ${$btnText}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="my-buttons" id="btn1" name="Nombre1" value="valor1">Botón 1</button>
<button class="my-buttons" id="btn2" name="Nombre2" value="valor2">Botón 2</button>
<button class="my-buttons" id="btn3" name="Nombre3" value="valo3">Botón 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que no intentas con lo siguiente. Le creas un ID a cada botón y desde js lo recuperas y ya lo mandas con ajax:

```
<button class='acceptbtn' id= "'.$accept++.'">Accept</button>


$( ".acceptbtn" ).click(function() {
     //Recuperas el ID del botón cliqueado
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     //Creas una variable, y le agregas el id recuperado
     var datos = new FormData();
     datos.append("id",id);
     //Envías los datos por ajax.
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "url.php",
         data: datos,
         success: function(){
             console.log("Yes");
         },
         error: function(){
             console.log("error");
         }
    });
 });
```

Espero te funcione. Saludos.